# Shelosha Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-three?

### ?שלושה ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 283.

Poppies have put the lazy gematria to sleep this time, or something.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-two entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Neis of Chanuka happened **283** years after the first Bais HaMikdash was destroyed.

3338 Destruction of First Temple and beginning of Babylonian Exile

3621 Rule of the Hasmonean dynasty begins

http://www.ou.org/chagim/chanukah/timeline.htm

Answer (score 3):

Mishna Torah - Sefer Zemanim - Hilchos Shabbos - Perek 28 - Halacha 5

היו שתי עיירות זו סמוכה לזו--אם יש ביניהן מאה וארבעים ואחת ושליש, כדי שיהיה שבעים אמה ושיירים לזו ושבעים אמה ושיירים לזו--חושבין שתיהן כעיר אחת; ונמצאת כל עיר מהן, מהלכת את כל העיר השנייה וחוצה לה אלפיים אמה.  היו שלושה כפרים משולשין--אם יש בין האמצעי ובין כל אחד מן החיצונים, אלפיים אמה או פחות מכאן, ובין השניים החיצונים, **מאתיים שלוש ושמונים** פחות שליש, כדי שיהיה בין כל אחד מהן ובין האמצעי כשתראה אותו כאילו הוא ביניהן, מאה אמה וארבעים ואחת ושליש--הרי שלושתן כמדינה אחת, ומודדין להם אלפיים אמה לכל רוח מחוץ לשלושתן.  עיר שהוקפה ולבסוף ישבה, מודדין לה מישיבתה; ישבה ולבסוף הוקפה, מודדין לה מחומותיה

Comment: A quick english summary would be nice

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munach

> The Munach מוּנַח, translating to English as "to rest," is a common
>   cantillation sound. It is marked with a right angle below the
>   corresponding word.
>
> The Munach is normally a short note. But when it is the first of two
>   Munachs followed by a Rivia, it has a longer melody. In this case it
>   may also be called legarmeh מוּנַח לְגַרְמֵ֣הּ.
>
> Munach occurs in the Torah 8777 times. **Munach Legarmeh occurs 283
>   times.** (Concordance of the Hebrew accents in the Hebrew Bible:
>   Concordance ..., Volume 1 By James D. Price, page 6)

Answer (score -2):

In Breshit 7:11 it tells us that in the 600 year, the second month, and the 17th day of Noah's life the flood started.

In Breshit 8:13 it tells us that in the 601 year, in the first month on the first day the ground was dry.

In Breshit 8:14 it tells us that the animals were let out of the ark in the second month, on the27th day of the month the earth was dry.  Beshit continues that this is when the animals were let out of the ark.

Therefore, the flood began on the  77th day of his 600th year and continued until the 31st day of his 601st year. But the animals did not exit the ark until 27 days later. So that would be 360 -77 = 283 days.

Therefore the flood lasted 283 days.

Comment: A year has a minimum of 353 days - less 1 month and 17 days would = 307 days.

Comment: Can you explain how that comes out to 283, please? If you count the months the same way in both verses, then I get no less that 302 days. If you're counting the months differently, please elaborate.

Comment: @jake and Gershon, I think Morah Hochman might be assuming that: (a) the months here are solar ones of 30 days each (an opinion that Ibn Ezra to Gen. 8:3 cites but rejects), and (b) that "the second month and the 17th day" means that two complete months plus 17 days had elapsed during the year. Which would leave 9 months of 30 days each = 270 days, plus 13 days. (If that's the case, Morah Hochman, then this isn't really correct: it means the 17th day of the 2nd month, so there'd be 10 complete months plus 13 or so days.)

Comment: @Alex, wouldn't you have to count in the occasional 31-day month?

Comment: As @Alex noted, you're counting month-day dates as (month_number)*30 + (day_number), when it should be (month_number -1)*30 + day_number.

Comment: From the 77th day of one year till the 31st day of the following year would be a minimum of 307 days. If you add 27 days for what you claim the animals stayed longer (source please) that would be 334. So please explain the number 283.

Comment: I need assume as Alex posted and I hold by that.  It seems, while not the conventional answer a plausible one.

Comment: `בַּחֹדֶשׁ הַשְּׁבִיעִי בְּאֶחָד לַחֹדֶשׁ יִהְיֶה לָכֶם שַׁבָּתוֹן זִכְרוֹן תְּרוּעָה מִקְרָא קֹדֶשׁ` So your Rosh HaShana comes out a month later than everyone else's. A certain R' Gamliel vs. R' Yehoshua story comes to mind. ;)